# What function will allow me to pull data from a column in a data frame based on the value in the columns in R?

Tags: r, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to pull data out of a dataframe from a specific column based on the value in the column.

For example:

```
foo    bar
x      13
x      26             
y      52
x      43
y      76

x.values <- some.function(foobar = data.frame, key.value = key value to sort by)
y.values <- some.function(foobar = data.frame, key.value = key value to sort by)
x.values
>>> (13, 26, 43)
y.values
>>> (53, 76)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is called df: Using Base R code:

```
x.values <- df[df$foo == "x",]$bar
y.values <- df[df$foo == "y",]$bar
```

This is similar to a "Where" clause in SQL. We're querying the dataframe's column "foo" for rows where foo == "x". If we add the "$bar" at the end of the statement, we will get the values for the bar column in the respective rows. However, if we omit the "$bar", the query will return the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is called `mydata`:

```
x.values <- mydata$bar[mydata$foo == "x"]
y.values <- mydata$bar[mydata$foo == "y"]
```